# Reverse-Lookup of Spotify Links

Tags: spotify

Does anyone know of a way to find the artist/album/track from a spotify link?
Example:
http://open.spotify.com/track/7hgtn706RqLE5q1mWe8aQx

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this: http://spotify.url.fi/ ?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at Spotify's [Metadata API lookup](http://developer.spotify.com/en/metadata-api/lookup/).

Answer (score 2):

To get neat, usable Spotify URLs, try http://cleanify.net